# Simple getter invoker with Byte buddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I am just learning byte buddy, and want to create the simplest getter invoker, but, unfortunately could find how to do it. So, the problem:

I have a lot classes, that I scan and if I find in a class a field that is annotated with `FooAnnotation` annotation I must be able to get the value of this field using this class instance getter method.

This is my code:

```
interface GetterInvoker<T, S> {

    //this method must `return instance.getterMethod()`;
    S getValueFrom(T instance);
}

abstract class AsbtractGetterInvoker implements GetterInvoker {
    //...some logic
}
```

Main code

```
//input
Class<?> scannedClass = ...
Field annotatedField = ....
Method getterMethod = ....

//generating class
Class<?> tempClass = new ByteBuddy()
    .subclass(AsbtractGetterInvoker.class, ConstructorStrategy.Default.IMITATE_SUPER_CLASS)
    .method(named("getValueFrom").and(takesArguments(1)))
    .intercept(???????)
    .make()
    .load(getClass().getClassLoader())
    .getLoaded();
```

Could anyone say how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd create such an implementation using `MethodCall` which allows you to do exactly this.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Ok, I can do `.intercept(MethodCall.invoke(getterMethod))` but how can I make bytebuddy call `getterMethod` on the instance I pass as argument?

Comment: Just run `MethodCall.invoke(getterMethod).on(0).withArgument(1)`.

Comment: `MethodCall.invoke(getterMethod).onArgument(0)` is what I needed. Thank you for giving the right direction.